# How to set android backend minSdk

Tags: android, server-side, google-cloud-endpoints

im working on an android app with some server-side business logic. Im using android studio and im creating that kind of app for a first time.

I am trying to use server-side application to login to a different system and return me a cookie, so my android application can tell, whether the set credentials are correct.

Here's my endpoint provided method.

```
/** Returns user with cookie set either to null or actual cookie from AIS */
@ApiMethod(name = "login")
public User login(@Named("loginName") String name, @Named("password") String password) {
    AISCommunicator aisCommunicator = new AISCommunicator();
    String cookieVal = aisCommunicator.login(password,name);

    User user = new User();
    user.setCookie(cookieVal);
    //user.setCookie("asdasdasd");

    return user;
}
```

AISCommunicator is a serverside bean. At the moment it's part of a code

```
CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
```

is marked as incorrect by Android studio, which tells me, that to use it, i need to declare minSdk level 9, while currently i have 1. How can i do that? I have set minSdk in my client's app, but it seems like it does not influence the serverside bean. 
Anyway, the code is still runnable for some reason and the endpoint Bean returns 404 not found error at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore Android Studio's error. This is one of its known and unfixed bugs.

Comment: Ok, lets say, that the required API is not the problem. Then it has to be the login method. It worked when i called it from client app tho, this is the code.. http://pastebin.com/6YFNKXgQ It returns error "404 not found" :(

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with your server-side Endpoints deployment. You'll need to do focused troubleshooting to narrow down the problem. For example, does this run in your local App Engine test install, but not on the server? What do the App Engine logs say? Try not putting any actual code in your endpoint to rule out some problem in there. Etc. You may need to take a step back and understand better how App Engine, Endpoints, deployment, and the Android Studio integration work.